# Multi-tenant server-to-server authentication - User consent issue

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I have followed this walkthrough to create a multi-tenant web application that can connect to Dynamics 365 CE Online. [Walkthrough: Multi-tenant server-to-server authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-multi-tenant-server-server-authentication).

When I ran the app for the first time and tried to sign in to the Dynamics CRM, it asked me to provide a consent that I accepted. And then it returned the below error:

> *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=AADSTS65001: **The user or administrator
> has not consented to use the application** with ID
> 'XXX' named 'MvcCrmStsWalkthrough'.
> Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.*

For subsequent tries, it didn't ask for consent. However, kept returning the aforementioned error.

#### What I have used for this POC

- Dynamics CRM Online trial
- Azure Active Directory service that was included by default with the CRM
  trial and was enough to perform application registration on Azure AD
- Visual Studio 2017 community edition

#### What I have tried so far

- In Azure AD I already have granted permission using the 'Grant Permission' button on the registered app Settings > Required Permissions (Seems accepting user consent through my custom app does the same)
- Setting oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to true in the Azure AD app manifest
- I verified that the O365 account that I am using to log in through the app has Global Administrator directory role in the AD

#### Sample code

Exactly the same as mentioned in the [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-multi-tenant-server-server-authentication)